# Good learning source for learning normalization

Tags: database-design, normalization

Can anyone recommend a good learning source to learn about database normalization from scratch please?

I referred to many youtube videos but they weren't fit to me.

Answer (score 1):

I know it's essentially a comic, but I keep it on my shelf for reference and to start conversations.  If you want something to talk about database normalization from scratch with good examples, I recommend "The Manga Guide to Databases by Mana Takahashi".  http://amzn.com/1593271905

Answer (score 1):

[Beginning Database Design](http://www.apress.com/9781430242093) was suggested in [High Performance MySQL](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/0636920022343.do). I've found this book to be a good, short enough to be to the point, introduction to database theory.